# getSupportedFlashModes on Camera2 API

Tags: android

I'm coding in the new `Camera2` API. I would like to get all supported flash modes, in the old API, i get do this by calling: `Camera.Parameters.getSupportedFlashModes()` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedFlashModes()). But in `Camera2` API, i can't find how to do that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
mCameraCharacteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraID);
mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE))
```

Comment: This method just check if device support flash or not.

Comment: mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES)

Comment: OFF/ON/ON_AUTO_FLASH/ON_ALWAYS_FLASH/ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE

Comment: [documentatin](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES) doesn't say about get flash modes supported...<br>Can you give me some more infomation?<br>By the way, thank for your support

Answer (score 1):

Flash mode values can be find in

```
int[] flashModeValues = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES);
```

where it will list the following values: (`OFF,ON,ON_AUTO_FLASH,ON_ALWAYS_FLASH,ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE`)